# How to make inline plots in Jupyter Notebook larger?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have made my plots inline on my Ipython Notebook with "`%matplotlib inline`."

Now, the plot appears.  However, it is very small.  Is there a way to make it appear larger using either notebook settings or plot settings?

[image]

Answer (score 293, accepted):

Yes, play with `figuresize` and `dpi` like so (before you call your subplot):

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(12,8), dpi= 100, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
```

As @tacaswell and @Hagne pointed out, you can also change the defaults if it's not a one-off:

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [12, 8]
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 100 # 200 e.g. is really fine, but slower
```

Comment: f, (ax1, ax2,ax3) = plt.subplots(1,3, sharex='col', sharey='row',figsize=(18, 16))    for this specific case

Comment: Does not work. Changing figsize in my case only changes the aspect ratio. The width of the total figure remains fixed

Comment: That is correct for numbers too large to fit on the page, then the scaling stops. It still can be useful for changing the aspect ratio as you noted.

Comment: Increasing dpi to '200' provides a much better result than just changing the figure size.

Comment: Yes, see @Hagne below.

Comment: how do you set figure size when fig is created by a `subplots` command: `fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2)`?

Answer (score 580):

The default figure size (in inches) is controlled by

```
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [width, height]
```

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [10, 5]
```

creates a figure with 10 (width) x 5 (height) inches

Comment: This is actually much more useful as a set-it-and-forget-it strategy if all one's plots are miss-sized.

Comment: Great. Struggled with pandas boxplot size and this fixed it. For some reason the `figsize=(x,y)` argument is ineffective in jupyter. However, modifying `matplob.rcParams`, as you suggest, works perfectly.

Comment: Make sure you run this _after_ running `%matplotlib inline`.

Comment: @uut isn't this the default?

Comment: @VerenaHaunschmid running `%matplotlib inline` after setting rcParams seems to overwrite the figure size back to default.

Comment: This was perfect solution for a for a quick-and-dirty three line (`nx.write_edgelist(G)` & `H=nx.read_edgelist()` & `nx.draw(H)`) NetworkX plot in Jupyter notebook.

Comment: You are definitely a Life Saver! Actually, I came from a totally different question and ended up here. After exhausting all the solutions, this one finally works! Really appreciate!

Answer (score 84):

I have found that `%matplotlib notebook` works better for me than inline with Jupyter notebooks.

Note that you may need to restart the kernel if you were using `%matplotlib inline` before.

Update 2019:
If you are running Jupyter Lab you might want to use
`%matplotlib widget`

Comment: Maybe this works in some cases but when I tried this on mine it gave me me a blank image with a pandas dataframe `df.plot()`. I had to go back to `%matplotlib inline`

Comment: @tsando I have seen an issue where switching from `%matplotlib inline` to `%matplotlib notebook` without restarting the kernel gives a blank output.

Switching from `%matplotlib notebook` to `%matplotlib inline` works fine.

Comment: Thanks @SlimCheney, I confirm what you say is true - it works if you restart the kernel

Comment: This definitely beats trying to set up panning and zoom components by hand

Comment: it does not work, even after restart the kernel. It gives a blank output

Comment: Any way to turn off interactive mode  by default?

Comment: Note that %matplotlib notebook no longer works with Jupyter Lab

Comment: @DanielKats I actually updated this answer in October 2019 to point out that in Jupyter Labs you should use %matplotlib widget

Comment: I had lots of trouble with `%matplotlib widget` until I followed [the instructions on the README](https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl#installation) (particularly `jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager`).

Answer (score 61):

If you only want the image of your figure to appear larger without changing the general appearance of your figure increase the figure resolution. Changing the figure size as suggested in most other answers will change the appearance since font sizes do not scale accordingly.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 200
```

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 28):

The question is about `matplotlib`, but for the sake of any R users that end up here given the language-agnostic title:

If you're using an R kernel, just use:

```
options(repr.plot.width=4, repr.plot.height=3)
```

Comment: Don't forget to load the "repr" package first: `library("repr")`

Answer (score 19):

To adjust the size of one figure:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
```

To change the default settings, and therefore all your plots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [15, 15]
```

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to scale the plot to full cell width.

1. Use `svg` format instead of bitmap when mainly plotting line charts:

```sh
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg'
```

2. Force the plot to be 100% width (paste into an empty cell):

```css
%%html
<style>
.output_svg div{
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
</style>
```

3. You may also want to change the aspect ratio or other parameters according to other answers for better insight.

It is not using public API and may stop working one day.
[image: screenshot of a full-width matplotlib plot]

Answer (score 7):

using something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.subplots(figsize=(18,8 ))
plt.subplot(1,3,1)
plt.subplot(1,3,2)
plt.subplot(1,3,3)
```

The output of the command

[image: the output of the command]

Answer (score 4):

A small but important detail for adjusting figure size on a one-off basis (as several commenters above reported "this doesn't work for me"):

You should do plt.figure(figsize=(,)) PRIOR to defining your actual plot.  For example:

This should correctly size the plot according to your specified figsize:

```
values = [1,1,1,2,2,3]
_ = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
_ = plt.hist(values,bins=3)
plt.show()
```

Whereas this will show the plot with the default settings, seeming to "ignore" figsize:

```
values = [1,1,1,2,2,3]
_ = plt.hist(values,bins=3)
_ = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is such an important point that I think someone should edit the answer to reflect this. This is all I wanted and couldn't for the life of me figure out why this was not working.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix to "plot overlap" is to use plt.tight_layout():

#### Example (in my case)

```
for i,var in enumerate(categorical_variables):
    plt.title(var)
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    df[var].hist()
    plt.subplot(len(categorical_variables)/2, 2, i+1)

plt.tight_layout()
```