# How to increase the size of my plot using plt.subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using colab notebook for generating some numbers using autoencoders. I am able to generate the numbers successfully but it is really small and invisible. I am using matplotlib for data viz.

Here is my `plot_image` function:

```
  def plot_image(image, shape=[28,28]):
     plt.imshow(image.reshape(shape), cmap="Greys", interpolation="nearest")
     plt.axis("off")
```

Here is my code for visualizing the numbers:

```
  for iteration in range(n_digits):
     plt.subplot(n_digits, 10, iteration+1)
     plot_image(outputs_val[iteration])
```

I am also using matplotlib inline function as:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

Can anyone guide me to visualize my result with a bigger plot? I am attaching the screenshot of my generated result.Thanks in advance guys.

[image: Here is the result of my numbers]

Comment: Sometimes my plots are small when I call `plt.show()` but then I can resize the window and it grows with it. Would that be applicable with %matplotlib inline? Or maybe instead of a 10 X 1 you could make a 5 X 2 or 3 X 3 and omit the last graph? Here is their documentation: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html?highlight=subplot#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot It tells you all the methods available to you, as well as some examples at the bottom you can look through!

Comment: i tried as you said but still its same. Let me go through the link that u mentioned. Thanks though

Comment: possible duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36367986/how-to-make-inline-plots-in-jupyter-notebook-larger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase the figure size by use the figure command. See below

```
def plot_image(image, shape=[28,28]):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 18)) # set the height and width in inches
    plt.imshow(image.reshape(shape), cmap="Greys", interpolation="nearest")
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks this works but can you explain little about height*width in inches? what are the ideal combo to use?